# Calling wrapped C++ DLL method from C#: passing addresses of integral variables to get output

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, dllimport

I need to call a wrapped function from a C++ DLL with the following declaration:

```
[DllImport(@dllPath, EntryPoint = "Calling_fooBar")]
private static extern int Calling_fooBar( uint*   a,
                                          uint*   b,
                                          uint*   c,
                                          uint*   d,
                                              //etc );
```

Used in this way:

```
private void getData()
{
    uint A, B, C, D; //etc
    Calling_fooBar( &A, &B, &C, &D );

    // ...
}
```

Upon doing this, A, B, C, D are all still 0.  I'm quite sure the external method in the DLL is working properly so they should have non-zero values.
So I'm guessing I'm passing the address wrong ... or something.

Hopefully this isn't too dumb a question.  I can clarify anything if needed

Comment: The DLL is pretty much a blackbox.  Using it to automate a testing software designed by another company, so I can't change it.

Comment: But what's the declaration in the header file?

Comment: int Calling_fooBar(
           uint* a,        
        uint* b,                   
        uint* c );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to Slaks above.  Here's what my code which successfully does such things looks like:

```
[DllImport("blah.dll")]
private static extern int thingy( ref uint refArg );
/* ... later in the code. ...*/
int retVal = thingy( ref refVariable );
```

Comment: hum.  Then maybe it IS something else, I'll keep checking
At least you guys have reassured me about the syntax.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `*` and `&` to `ref`.